# Reading file from sys directory

Tags: android

He is my code:

```
File f;
    FileInputStream inputStream;
    byte[] buffer = null;
    try {
        f=new File("/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq");
        if(f.exists()){
        inputStream =  new FileInputStream(f);
        inputStream.read(buffer);
        }


         Log.i("informacja","Czytam");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block

        Log.i("informacja",e.toString());
    }
```

File path is correct, File exists. But always in inputStream.read(buffer) i get NullPointerException.
This is part of my Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Can anyone suggest me where I made a mistake?

@Update. Thanks for the code snippet. Now i can read but:
this is what I get :  [B@41a743c8
What I should get: 1000000

Comment: Is it really an external storage path? Can I suggest you to check external path? Look there: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: I dont think so. They are permissions -r--. And more i can read this file with antek explorer

Comment: I apologize. You were right

Comment: I edited my answer, please check it :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to read the output of cat

```
    ProcessBuilder cmd;
    String result = "";

    try {
        String[] args = { "/system/bin/cat", "/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq" };
        cmd = new ProcessBuilder(args);

        Process process = cmd.start();
        InputStream in = process.getInputStream();
        byte[] re = new byte[32768];
        int read = 0;
        while ( (read = in.read(re, 0, 32768)) != -1) {
            String string = new String(re, 0, read);
            Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), string);
            result += string;
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
```

and open it as normal file

```
    String result = "";

    try {

        File file = new File("/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq");
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
        byte[] re = new byte[32768];
        int read = 0;
        while ( (read = in.read(re, 0, 32768)) != -1) {
            String string = new String(re, 0, read);
            Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), string);
            result += string;
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
```

Answer (score 1):

Android applications don't run as root on an unmodified device so you cant read from `/sys` folder without rooting the device.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies here --> `byte[] buffer = null;` and `inputStream.read(buffer);`

the buffer is still null, try this one :

```
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(f);
    byte[] b = new byte[is.available()];
    is.read(b);
```

hope this helps, good luck ^^

P.S. Don't forget to set all necessary permission

**Edit** :

To read the file, you will need to parse it.
The string result from the content of the string can be gotten with :`String fileContent = new String(b); //the byte we read earlier`

from there, you must parse the file to get the value you need. In order to parse the file, you will have to know the file structure and create parsing method as needed.